# Avoiding <sos> and <eos> being parsed by Spacy

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, spacy

I am stuck with a basic thing but I could not figure out how to make it work. My apologies if it is something super basic. It is just that I am very new to Spacy and do not know how to do this. Could not find any resource on the internet as well.

I have a bunch of sentences like so

```py
a = "<sos> Hello There! <eos>"
```

I am using this following lines of code to tokenize it using Spacy

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
for token in nlp(a):
    print(token.text)
```

What it prints is something like this

```
<
sos
>
Hello
There
!
<
eos
>
```

As you can see, it parsed the `<sos>` and `<eos>` metatags. How can I avoid that? The output I would like to see is something like the following

```
<sos>
Hello
There
!
<eos>
```

I could not figure out how to achieve this. Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In spaCy, tokenizer checks for exceptions before splitting text. 
You need to add an exception to tokenizer to treat your symbols as full tokens.

Your code should look like this:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.attrs import ORTH, LEMMA

sent = "<sos> Hello There! <eos>"

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('<sos>', [{ORTH: "<sos>"}])
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('<eos>', [{ORTH: "<eos>"}])

for token in nlp(sent):
    print(token.text)
```

You can read more about it here:
https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#add_special_case